# Generic User based Recommender with Pseudo Recommender Job on Mahout

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

i am trying to run the Pseudo Recommender with the Generic User Based Recommender on Mahout. But it is giving IllegalStateException>. I figured out might be due to the fact that
Pseudo Recommender requires class with just DataModel as parameter whereas GenericUserbasedRecommender requires Datamodel, neighborhood, similarity parameters.
So, can anyone help me regarding how to use GenericUserbasedRecommender with PseudoRecommenderJob on Mahout.

Comment: Please give your stacktrace here.